# Swift Closure Error

Tags: swift, closures

I'm relatively new to swift and experimenting with the closure syntax

This runs fine:

```
fileUpdater.run({ path in println("\(path)") })
```

But I can't get this to work:

```
    fileUpdater.run({ (path: String) -> () in {
        for file in self.changedFiles {

        }
        self.changedFiles.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
        println("mounted \(path)")
    }})
```

Fails with the error

> Cannot invoke run with an argument list of type ((String) -> ())

Here is the function definition:

```
func run(function: (path: String) -> ()) { // more code
```

**UPDATE:** The following now passes basic checks but then makes LLVM fail.

```
fileUpdater.run({ path in {
    return println("mounted \(path)")
}})
```

What a horrible error message:

```
Global is external, but doesn't have external or weak linkage!
i8* ()*    @_TFFFC10SwiftTest211AppDelegate11updateFilesFS0_FT_T_U0_FSST_auL_4pathSS
invalid linkage type for function declaration
i8* ()* @_TFFFC10SwiftTest211AppDelegate11updateFilesFS0_FT_T_U0_FSST_auL_4pathSS
LLVM ERROR: Broken module found, compilation aborted
```

I'm using Xcode 6.4 (so I think Swift 1.x?), if that helps.

Comment: Does defining it as `func run(function: (String) -> ())` help? I can’t reproduce this.

Comment: No sorry that doesn't help

Comment: Could you show us your `run` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra curly braces around the block body. They are neither needed nor allowed.

This is wrong:

```
fileUpdater.run({ path in { < curly brace not allowed
    println("mounted \(path)")
}})
^
curly brace not allowed
```

This is correct:

```
fileUpdater.run({ path in
    println("mounted \(path)")
})
```